# Loop through each obj in a json call using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm quite new to json/jQuery and javascript so I may be doing something glaringly stupid, so go easy on me. Also, I HAVE looked at questions asking similar things to what I'm asking, but I couldn't seem to get any of them to work for me.

What I am trying to do, is call json data from an API and get the "image.full" property for each object. The included JSfiddle shows what I am trying to accomplish, although I have statically assigned to get the image of a single character(object) "Aatrox" in this case. I have supplied sample data for two characters(objects) "Thresh" and "Aatrox"

**Sample json data:**

```
{
 "data": {
   "Thresh": {
     "id": "Thresh",
     "title": "the Chain Warden",
     "name": "Thresh",
     "image": {
        "w": 48,
        "full": "Thresh.png",
        "sprite": "champion3.png",
        "group": "champion",
        "h": 48,
        "y": 0,
        "x": 48
     },
     "key": "412"
  },
  "Aatrox": {
     "id": "Aatrox",
     "title": "the Darkin Blade",
     "name": "Aatrox",
     "image": {
        "w": 48,
        "full": "Aatrox.png",
        "sprite": "champion0.png",
        "group": "champion",
        "h": 48,
        "y": 0,
        "x": 0
     },
     "key": "266"
  },
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="champs"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.getJSON('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1/champion?  champData=image&api_key=7d315bdf-c456-4792-b5d6-eadc7ef1672f', function (json) {
    var image = json.data.Aatrox.image.full;
    $('#champs').append('<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"><img   src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.3.18/img/champion/' + image + '"/></div>');
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/8S8LZ/2/

**Question Summary:** How can I loop through and get the "image.full" property of each object within data (ie: Thresh, Aatrox)? Also, I realize my API key is shown in this question, so I will be getting a new one after this is sorted out. :)

Any help is greatly appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quick and dirty, but if you loop through each object and access its image property in much the same way you're doing now, I modified your fiddle to create a list of objects:

```
$.getJSON('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1/champion?champData=image&api_key=7d315bdf-c456-4792-b5d6-eadc7ef1672f', function (json) {
    $.each(json.data, function(ix, obj) {

var image = obj.image.full;
$('#champs').append('<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.3.18/img/champion/' + image + '"/></div>');
});

});
```

Here is my version of your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/zfF8u/

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this apart:

- First, we need to translate the object properties to an array, this is done with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- Then, we can perform property access and return each `full` property, this is done with [`Array::map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Something like

```
var images = Object.keys(json.data).map(function(key){
    return json.data[key].image.full
});
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/568gp/)

Comment: How would I incorporate my $.getJSON into that?

Comment: @MathewMacLean I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here, you'd put that code inside your `$.getJSON`?

Comment: What would that look like all tied together? I'm trying it and it I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @MathewMacLean it returns an array. You use the code in order to grab the images and then use a `for` loop to iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var prop in json.data) {
    if (json.data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop.image.full);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you performing that `.hasOwnProperty` check?

Comment: checking that is standard for iterating through a JSON. It allows you to make sure you're looking at an actual JSON property and not something else like a function of the objects prototype.

Comment: Why would the object's prototype have any enumerable functions o_0?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's necessary to have in there

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var k in json.data) {
    var image = json.data[k].image.full;
    $('#champs').append('<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"><img   src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.3.18/img/champion/' + image + '"/></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery like so:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    console.log(value.image.full);
});
```

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/8S8LZ/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the json.data to a variable and loop through it using jquery's each loop

```
var data = json.data;
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    var full = value.image.full;  //alternatively value['image']['full'];

    // do whatever you want with full variable
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it.
Loop through the response, and then append it.

You want to save the selector in a variable because its faster than querying the dom each time in the loop.

Also here is a fork of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwhT6/1/

```
$.getJSON('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1/champion?champData=image&api_key=7d315bdf-c456-4792-b5d6-eadc7ef1672f', function (json) {
    var $champContainer = $("#champs")

    for (var key in json.data) {
        var champ = json.data[key]
         ,  image = champ.image.full

        $champContainer.append('<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.3.18/img/champion/' + image + '"/></div>')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8S8LZ/5/)?

```
$.getJSON('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1/champion?champData=image&api_key=7d315bdf-c456-4792-b5d6-eadc7ef1672f', function( json ) {
    var image = json.data.Aatrox.image.full;    
    console.log(json);
    $.each(json.data,function(key,value){
        var name=value.image.full;
         $('#champs').append( '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1"><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.3.18/img/champion/' + name + '"/></div>');
    });
});
```